# How to improve my composition pattern codes?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to build a simple Composition pattern sample. Basically the output will be  each department employees' total intelligent. I have created 3 types of employee and 2 departments.Please see the following codes:

Employee Class

```
abstract class Employee {

    function addEmployee(Employee $employee){

    }

    function removeEmployee(){

    }

    abstract function showIntelligent();

}
```

Minion class

```
class Minion extends Employee {

       function showIntelligent(){
          return '100';
    } 


}
```

Manager class

```
class Manager extends Employee {

    function showIntelligent(){
           return '150';
    } 



}
```

Sales Department Class

```
class SalesDept extends Employee {

     private $_deptEmployee=array();
    function addEmployee(Employee $employee){

        $this->_deptEmployee[]=$employee;

    }

    function removeEmployee(){
        if(!empty($this->_deptEmployee)){
            array_pop($this->_deptEmployee);
        }else{
            echo 'no employees in Sales Department';
        }
    }

    function showIntelligent() {

        $totalInt=0;
        foreach ($this->_deptEmployee as $employee){

            $totalInt += $employee->showIntelligent();
        }
        echo 'Total Intelligent of the Sales Department Employees is: '.$totalInt;
    }

}
```

Design Department Class

```
class DesignDept extends Employee {

     private $_deptEmployee=array();
    function addEmployee(Employee $employee){

        $this->_deptEmployee[]=$employee;

    }

    function removeEmployee(){
        if(!empty($this->_deptEmployee)){
            array_pop($this->_deptEmployee);
        }else{
            echo 'no employees in Design Department';
        }
    }

   function showIntelligent() {

        $totalInt=0;
        foreach ($this->_deptEmployee as $employee){

            $totalInt += $employee->showIntelligent();
        }
        echo 'Total Intelligent of the Design Department Employees is: '.$totalInt;
    }


}
```

My index

```
    $salesDpt=new SalesDept();
    $salesDpt->addEmployee(new Manager());
    $salesDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $salesDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $salesDpt->addEmployee(new GeneralManager());

    $salesDpt->showIntelligent();



    $DesignDpt=new DesignDept();
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Manager());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Manager());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion());
    $DesignDpt->addEmployee(new GeneralManager());

    $DesignDpt->showIntelligent();
```

It seems like that I have to use lots of codes to add new employees. Is this a good practice? Anyway to improve it? Thanks for any advises.

Comment: Since when is a department an employee?  What do "addEmployee" and "removeEmployee" mean in the classes Minion and Manager? Seems like they don't belong there.

Comment: @Styxxy are you saying Employee is a bad superclass name? If so, I can change it to Company, and I will have to move AddEmployee and removeEmployee methods out of Employee Class.  Thanks for the advise.

Comment: It is not a bad name as super class (abstract) for Minion and Manager. However, it is not an appropriate name for your department classes.

Comment: Other comments: if you are planning on calculating values, don't return your integers as strings (refer to your showIntelligent() methods in Minion and Manager), just return the plain integers.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat yourself 7 times by writing the add method as shown in your example, use a (for)loop or whatever to reduce the lines of code. Apart from that, if you want all unique objects, there is no way around than adding them one by one (or create an add method that accepts an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a number of comments - some of which have already been mentioned.

1) Having an Employee class with subclasses of Minion and Manager isn't a good idea.  The problem here is that Minions can be promoted to Managers and that shouldn't require you to throw away the old objects and replace them with a new ones.  Instead, have one class for Employee with a "role" instance variable containing a MinionRole or a ManagerRole.  With this design, you can replace the role without replacing the whole Employee object. In fact, from what you've described so far, you don't need roles at all - just an instance variable for the intelligence.

2) The department classes shouldn't inherit from Employee.  A department isn't an employee and can't be used as a replacement for an employee.  Create a new class called Department. Do you really need subclasses?  Would it be enough to have instances of Department where each department has a name (Sales, Design, etc?)  Do you really want to have to modify, recompile, repackage and redeploy the application if you add an Accounting department?

Subclassing is only useful when the subclasses have different behavior.  In your case, the subclasses have the same behavior or close enough that a simple instance variable would make it work.  Don't get too excited about inheritance.  Inheritance isn't the answer to all problems and should be used carefully.  Alan Kay, the creator of the Smalltalk programming language and the person who coined the term "object oriented" never liked the concept of inheritance and only reluctantly accepted it to allow better code sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change addEmployee() method to take an integer count argument.

This can decrease 7 lines of code to the following :

```
$DesignDpt->addEmployee(new Minion(), 7);
```

Comment: Then you always add the same "Minion" (unless you clone).

Comment: Yes, but depending on the requirements this can be the exactly expected behaviour.

Comment: I doubt it since he wants to add 7 minions. If you do what you do, you will always use the same reference and thus changing all objects rather than only the required object.

Comment: OK, but if the aim is to calculate the total intelligence of the department and the intelligence is only affected by the type of Employee, then you can simply store how many of each employee type works in a department. On the other hand, if the author of the question wants to maintain every single employee in a department, for further use for instance, then you are right.

Comment: True that; but in this example there is just so much wrong. Without the real intent of the author, it is hard to suggest any more improvements (rather than remove half of his code).